# Most efficient way to run many repetitions of an Rcpp function for a simulation study?

Tags: r, simulation, rcpp, sampling

I wrote an Rcpp function that returns a sample from a population, and to test the estimation method I'd like to run it thousands or millions of times. It seems that invoking Rcpp takes a little bit of overhead, and something like `replicate(100,myFunction())` is taking much longer than I would expect.

What's the best way to do this? `rep`,`*apply`, `replicate`, put the loop itself in C++?

Comment: I normally use sapply for something like this but replicate is just a repackaged sapply so should take about the same time.  What's the `myFunction()` that you're calling? Could that be tweaked to get the run time down?

Comment: Not easily I don't think. My function is a reimplimentation of the UPtille function from the sampling package, which samples using Tille's method. It iterates N-k times to produce a sample of k, and in my case N=4600 and k=40.

Comment: I would do the `for` loop in C++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are concerned about performance you want to minimize the number of calls from R to C++ -- and not do it *thousands or millions of times* as you said.

So Baptiste is spot on: do the `for()` loop at the C++ level, if you can.

Also note that the most recent version of [RcppArmadillo](http://cran.r-project.org/package=RcppArmadillo) now has a C++ version of `sample()` which may allow you to do that part in C++ too.   That saidm I know nothing about "UPtille" and what it does so maybe you are stuck with the existing R implementation.

Comment: It didn't seem to make a huge difference, but I think one iteration of my code just dwarfs the overhead. The sample() function would be tons faster, but I'm using Tille's method because I need it to have certain properties. Runtime for one iteration is something like 8sec on a Core2Duo, which is probably about as optimal as I can get it